# Is there a way I can automate the login operation without opening browser?

Tags: python, bots, python-telegram-bot

I need to automate the login operation on [bidoo](https://it.bidoo.com/login_push.php). I tried with

```
r = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
urlopen(r).read()
time.sleep(1) #Sleep to wait the login page to show 
log = json.dumps({'username': 'foo','password': 'bar'})
r = requests.post(url, data = log)
```

But it didn't work.
I thought Selenium could have solved my problem, but I cannot use a browser since I need to use my script on a vps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using requests's [Session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) object.

```
session = requests.Session()
response = s.post(login_url, verify=False, data={'username': 'foo','password': 'bar'})
```

and the subsequent requests can be done using `session` object

Comment: Sorry, but it seems not to be working. It is hard to determine because bidoo's html pages are a big mess... But the script is not working as expected

Comment: I don't see login page at all in the link mentioned in question.

Comment: What do you mean? I do see login page. It appears as a "popup" on the screen